# Trick Python into running an application in another directory

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.5

I have a script in the `C:\Users\Username\Project` directory.  To complete its task, it has to call an installed program, verify the program opened correctly, then go through a series of steps while the program is still running.  However, in all cases, it returns an "Access is denied" error.  Bare minimum sample code to duplicate is below:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['"C:\\Program Files\\Application\\Appname.exe"', '--targetdirectory', '"C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Target Folder"'])
```

This always results in `CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied`.

Similar methods that have also resulted in error 5:

- subprocess.call()
- os.system()

Other fixes that have not addressed the issue:

- Running as administrator
- Changing the application directory to be owned by the running user

So, if changing permissions doesn't fix a permissions issue, how can Python 2.5 be tricked into running an installed program?

Comment: Have you tried keeping the file that has to be run on another drive like d or e in which os is not there ??

Comment: Have you tried using "C:\\Program Files\\Application\\Appname.exe" instead of '"C:\\Program Files\\Application\\Appname.exe"'? Same goes for the other one.

Comment: I just tried the thing with the single and double quotes and it works. Have you tried to use only one argument? Is the error different if you do that?

Comment: Matthias Schreiber:  Changing single quotes to double quotes caused it to work.  Wish https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen had documented this fact...  Go ahead and submit as answer.